Why does SteamworksPy fail to load/retrieve data?
import ctypes
import glob
import os

from steamworks import STEAMWORKS
from steamworks.exceptions import SteamNotRunningException


class SteamClass:
    def __init__(self):  

        # Specify the directory containing the DLLs (use current working directory as an example)
        dll_directory = os.getcwd()

        # Add and load all DLLs from the specified directory
        loaded_dlls = self.add_and_load_all_dlls(dll_directory)

        self.steamworks = STEAMWORKS()
        # - SteamNotLoadedException  : STEAMWORKS class has not yet been loaded
        # - SteamNotRunningException : Steam is not running
        # - SteamConnectionException : The API connection to Steam could not be established 
        # - GenericSteamException    : A generic exception occured (retry when encountering this)
        try: 
            self.steamworks.initialize()
        except SteamNotRunningException:
            print(SteamNotRunningException)
            exit()
        except OSError:
            print(OSError)
            exit()
        
        self.login()


    # Function to add all DLLs in a given directory to the DLL search path and load them
    def add_and_load_all_dlls(self, directory):
        # Add the specified directory to the DLL search path
        os.add_dll_directory(directory)
        
        # Get all DLL files in the specified directory
        dll_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.dll'))
        
        loaded_dlls = {}
        
        for dll in dll_files:
            try:
                # Attempt to load the DLL
                loaded_dlls[dll] = ctypes.CDLL(dll)
                print(f"{os.path.basename(dll)} was successfully loaded.")
            except OSError as e:
                print(f"Failed to load {os.path.basename(dll)}: {e}")
        
        return loaded_dlls

    def login(self):
        """
        Execute two basic calls from the SteamUsers interface to retrieve SteamID from logged in user and Steam profile level 
        """
        my_steam64 = self.steamworks.Users.GetSteamID()
        my_steam_level = self.steamworks.Users.GetPlayerSteamLevel()

        print(f'Logged on as {my_steam64}, level: {my_steam_level}')
    
    def store_data(self):
         # Store the updated stats to Steam
        store_success = self.steamworks.UserStats.StoreStats()
        if store_success:
            print("Data stored successfully.")
        else:
            print("Failed to store data.")
        pass

    def get_stat(self, STAT_ID):
        if (self.steamworks.UserStats.RequestCurrentStats() == True):
            print('Stats successfully retrieved!')
        else:
            print('Failed to get stats. Shutting down.')
            exit(0)
        stat = self.steamworks.UserStats.GetStatInt(STAT_ID)
        return stat

    def set_stat(self, STAT_ID, num):   #   STAT_CURRENT_STAGE, 1
        if (self.steamworks.UserStats.RequestCurrentStats() == True):
            print('Stats successfully retrieved!')
        else:
            print('Failed to get stats. Shutting down.')
            exit(0)
        stat = self.steamworks.UserStats.GetStatInt(STAT_ID)
        stat += num
        self.steamworks.UserStats.SetStat('STAT_CURRENT_STAGE', stat)
        self.store_data()
        pass

    # Function to unlock an achievement
    def unlock_achievement(self, achievement_id):
        # Check if the achievement is already unlocked
        ach_status = self.steamworks.UserStats.GetAchievement(achievement_id)
        if ach_status:
            print(f"Achievement '{achievement_id}' is already unlocked.")
        else:
            # Unlock the achievement
            success = self.steamworks.UserStats.SetAchievement(achievement_id)
            if success:
                # Store the updated stats to Steam
                store_success = self.steamworks.UserStats.StoreStats()
                if store_success:
                    print(f"Achievement '{achievement_id}' unlocked and stored successfully.")
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to store achievement '{achievement_id}'.")
            else:
                print(f"Failed to set achievement '{achievement_id}'.")


steam = SteamClass()

stages_complete = steam.get_stat('STAT_STAGES_COMPLETE')
stages_complete += 10
steam.set_stat('STAT_STAGES_COMPLETE', stages_complete)
stages_complete = steam.get_stat('STAT_STAGES_COMPLETE')
print(f'STAGES COMPLETE: {stages_complete}')
ACH_STAGE_1 = steam.steamworks.UserStats.GetAchievement('ACH_STAGE_1')
steam.unlock_achievement('ACH_STAGE_1')
print(ACH_STAGE_1)
print(steam.unlock_achievement('ACH_STAGE_1'))

My output is the following [This is not my SteamID]:
SteamworksPy64.dll was successfully loaded.
steam_api64.dll was successfully loaded.
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 480
SteamInternal_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  1234123123123123 [API loaded no]
Logged on as 1234123123123123 , level: 2
Stats successfully retrieved!
Stats successfully retrieved!
Data stored successfully.
Stats successfully retrieved!
STAGES COMPLETE: 0
Failed to set achievement 'ACH_STAGE_1'.
False
Failed to set achievement 'ACH_STAGE_1'.
None

So how do I use SteamworksPy to retrieve the data correctly (this is not my Steam ID) or am I retrieving the stored data incorrectly? I am using the Windows64 version of SteamworksAPI. Also, it appears to say that the API wasn't loaded, so why is that?

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but I was having a tough time getting any achievement to unlock and display for me in my game testing until I found the below answer and added a 'b' to my code. Changed from:
self.steamworks.UserStats.SetAchievement('EASY_CASUAL')

to:
self.steamworks.UserStats.SetAchievement(b'EASY_CASUAL')

The b before 'EASY_CASUAL' in b'EASY_CASUAL' is used to indicate that the string is a byte string.
In Python, strings are sequences of characters and they are stored as Unicode. However, when you’re dealing with data from files, networks, or APIs, you often need to work with bytes. This is where byte strings come in.
A byte string is a string of bytes, not characters. It doesn’t have an encoding (like UTF-8, ASCII, etc.). When you put a b before a string in Python, you’re telling Python to treat the string as a byte string.
In this case, b'EASY_CASUAL' is a byte string. This is apparently required by the SetAchievement method in the Steamworks module. If you’re getting an error or unexpected behavior, you might want to check the documentation or source code of the Steamworks module to see if it requires byte strings.
